# How to format labels with leading zeroes?

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-2, leading-zero

I'm trying to display a number next to a symbol in QGIS 2.0.1 - The numbers are from an integer-field in a PostgreSQL database.

The goal is that single digit numbers get a leading 0 (zeros). Examples:

- 12 --> 12
- 10 --> 10
- 9 --> 09
- 0 --> 00

In the menu

```
 layer properties --> labelling --> formating
```

I switch on "number formatting" and then enter a custom expression. I tried these two codes with various combinations of ", ' and more brackets, but none of them work:

- ```sql
  CASE WHEN "Value" < 10 THEN rpad("Value", 2, 0) END
  ```
- ```sql
  CASE WHEN "Value" < 10 THEN "0" || "Value" END
  ```

For any other person having trouble with this: *Turn of "number formatting".* It seems to be the reason why leading zeros are removed from the `rpad()` function.

Enter the following in the regular "layer labeling" box:

```
  rpad("Field", 2, 0)
```

and everything will work fine. But if you also activate number formatting it will take away the leading zeros.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is the [`rpad()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#rpad) function for that:

| input | function | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `rpad('1', 2, '0')` | 01 |
| 10 | `rpad('10', 2, '0')` | 10 |

For using this function for your field:

```
rpad("yourcolumn", 2, '0')
```

> rpad() function
>
> Returns a string with supplied width padded using the
> fill character.
>
> Syntax rpad(string, width, fill)
>
> Arguments
>
> string - is string. The string.
> width - is int. The length of the new string.
> fill - is char. The character to padd the remaining space with.
>
> Example
>
> rpad('Hello', 10, 'x') → 'xxxxxHello'

Comment: I tried: rpad("Value", 2, '0') but nothing changes. Does that work with Integer field or do I need to convert to string?

Comment: Just try `lpad` for sec.  I think there was a bug (fixed now) and the functions where wrong.

Comment: Yes lpad works and converts 2 into 20.

Comment: Could you find out if the function "rpad" is broken? Maybe I can donate for the bug to be prioritized?

Comment: Nope not broken.

Comment: It certainly seems like it is broken for me. And it is really weird that lpad works just fine.

Comment: What about just manual `rpad('1', 2, '0')`

Comment: Same thing. rpad doesn't work, lpad works with your example. Maybe my operating system? (German Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit, QGIS 2.0.1)

Answer (score 16):

Working on QGIS 2.18.20 I see a different behavior of the one described by @NathanW:

```
lpad("id",2,'0')-> '02'

rpad("id",2,'0')-> '20'
```

Where I think ***r*** stands for **r**ight and ***l*** for **l**eft.

Quoting the man page of the function `rpad`:

> Returns a string padded to supplied width using a fill character.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> rpad(string, width, fill)
>
> **Arguments**
>
> *string* string to pad
>
> *width* length of new string
>
> *fill* character to pad the remaining space with
>
> **Examples**
>
> rpad('Hello', 10, 'x') → 'Helloxxxxx'

Comment: Same here on QGIS 3.6.