# Adding leading zeros to string value in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, leading-zero

I have a `"field"` with string values like

| field | new field |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 0003 |
| 5 | 0005 |
| 22 | 0022 |
| 999 | 0999 |

What is the right expression for the QGIS Field calculator to get a 4-character string-field like `"new field"`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format labels with leading zeroes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83338/how-to-format-labels-with-leading-zeroes) i.e. [`lpad("field", 4, 0)`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#lpad)

Comment: Yes, perfect! Thanks for pointing this out, I couldn't find it by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Field calculator "lpad" does what you want:

> Returns a string padded on the left to the specified width, using a fill character. If the target width is smaller than the string's length, the string is truncated.

> Syntax: lpad(string,width,fill)

so in your case it would be:

```
lpad("Your_field_name",4,'0')
```